# How to use slimframework 4 on a server

Tags: php, apache, slim

I was using slim framework 3 for my rest api on Apache server. The request and responses was sent to routes I created for example http://example.com/public/show/names

Now I'm going to use version 4 and it's running on port 8080 by itself.
On local it's running with command `composer start`.
So I can't use it in my online web server.
I want to use routing as it was in version 3.
How should I use it on my web server?

Comment: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/deployment/deployment.html

Comment: The internal PHP web server is not intended for use in production. You can continue to use Apache as before.